# Send and Receive Images in Bytes

Tags: python, opencv, flask

I want to send and receive images using Python and Flask. My current solution does not work.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/add_face', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_face():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #  read encoded image
        imageString = base64.b64decode(request.form['img'])
        #  convert binary data to numpy array
        nparr = np.fromstring(imageString, np.uint8)
        #  let opencv decode image to correct format
        img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR);
        cv2.imshow("frame", img)
        cv2.waitKey(0)

    return "list of names & faces"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

client:

```
import requests
import base64

URL = "http://localhost:5000/add_face"

#first, encode our image with base64
with open("block.png", "rb") as imageFile:
    img = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

response = requests.post(URL, data={"name":"obama", "img":str(img)})
print(response.content)
```

error:

```
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)\nbinascii.
Error: Incorrect padding\n\n-->\n'
```

Comment: Why have you removed all the `import` statements (which must presumably be in your code) so that no-one can run it?

Comment: Please check your indentation, particularly under the `with` statement.

Comment: i am sorry i added it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are parsing the request correctly on the server. Also the variable 'imageString' is actually binary since it's the result of decoding the 'img' string from the post request

Try changing

```
imageString = base64.b64decode(request.form['img'])
```

to

```
req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
imageString = base64.b64decode(req.get('img'))
```